# className in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've a react code as shown below in which I want to add a className at **Line Z** conditionally in React when **Line A** doesn't render anything

When `Line A` doesn't render anything, I want to add `className` `hide` `(at Line Z)`  `(hide { display: none })` so that it can hide the entire `abc-def` `div`. I found a solution from their official website but I am unable to integrate it in my code above.

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#how-do-i-add-css-classes-to-components

Answer (score 0):

Use inline styling with conditions as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead off calling those functions inline, consider calling them before the `render()` function, so you can check the contents;

```
const renderPrograms = () => {
    return programs.map((program, index)=>{
        return (
            <a href={program.url} key={index}>
                <div className="program" >
                    <div class="hello-world">{program.name}</div>
                </div >
            </a>
        )
    })
}

const lineA = programs && renderPrograms();
const lineBClassName = (!lineA) ? ' hide' : '';

return(
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div className ="pqr-xyz">  
            <h5>Hello World</h5>            
        </div>
        <div className={"abc-def" + lineBClassName}>        
            <h5>Programs</h5>
            {lineA}
        </div>
    </div> 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since *programs* is an array, you can check it first

This is a conditional rendering solution

```js
return(
 <div class="parent-div">
  <div className ="pqr-xyz">  
     <h5>Hello World</h5>            
  </div>
  {programs.length && 
  <div className="abc-def hello-world">
     <h5>Programs</h5>
    {renderPrograms()}
   </div>}
 </div> 
 )
```

Conditional class solution

```js
return(
 <div class="parent-div">
  <div className ="pqr-xyz">  
     <h5>Hello World</h5>            
  </div>
  // if the length is 0 or the array is empty then add hide class
  <div className={`abc-def ${!programs.length && "hide"}`}>
     <h5>Programs</h5>
    {programs.length && renderPrograms()}
   </div>
 </div> 
 )
```

Anyway, You can also check [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) library, it's more effective way to add conditional class in react